# SQL avoid inserting duplicate new shopping cart id

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

(First and foremost, sorry for my bad English, it is not my first language.)

I have a SQL database table to store some shopping cart, that likes something like this:

`Shopcart`
`----------`
`ID(PK)  shopcartid     price     user`
`1         S123         112.00    Tom`
`2         S124         6543.00   Mary`
`3         S125         456.00    James`
`4         S126         25.00     Peter`

Since the database was not set by me, I don't have much knowledge with the internal designs, proprieties, etc.

As far as I know for the database design wise,
ID column, 
Allow NULL: No
Type: int
(Is Identity): Yes
shopcartid column, 
Allow NULL: No
Type: nvarchar(100)

There is also an clustered index set.
Name: PK_shopcart
Columns: ID(ASC),shopcartid(ASC)
Is Unique: Yes
Type: Primary Key

The website (in php) will create a shopping cart (`INSERT INTO Shopcart shopcartid price user VALUES {new shopcartid} {price} {user}`) once the user login to the site and if they don't already have a shopping cart assigned. What is a MUST is that the shopcartid to not duplicate. While ID is also unique, it should be auto-increment(?)(not sure). However, currently, the shopcartid keeps on duplicating as we add more shopping cart.

The way the site creates the shopcartid, originally was to use `SELECT COUNT(*) AS value FROM Shopcart`, and add 1 to the shopcartid, which most definitely don't work and will create duplicates.

What I proposed was to get the last shopcartid by getting the latest added shopping cart by ID which should be unique, and add 1 to that.:
`SELECT shopcartid
from Shopcart
where ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Shopcart)`

However, my colleague said it could still have possibility of creating duplicate shopcartid since with many concurrent users visiting the site, it could be possible that the fetch the same ID, thus the same shopcartid, and created a duplicated new shopcartid.

So here is my question, what is the best way to avoid creating a duplicate shopcartid, and how could this be achieved.

Comment: You should just use `id` as the shopping cart id, and dispense with the additional column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a Sequencer for setting the ID of the shopping cart. Each time a user wants to create a new shopping cart, the sequenzer provides a new, unique ID.

Comment: sequence is to create a number, right? So I would need to get the number from the sequence, then create an shopcartid from it inside the create shopping cart function. But what would happened if say two new user login to the site and both trigger the create shopping cart function at the same exact time, would they both get the same number from the sequencer?

Comment: yes, it can create a number. No, they would not get the same number. The sequencer returns only unique (ascending) numbers.

Comment: just found out that it's running on SQL Server 2008, which if I correct doesn't support sequence? Could using identity, similar to method suggested from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number/ (option2), achieved the same?

Answer (score 0):

Use transactions to avoid duplication and Put unique key constraint on shopcartid to make sure that no duplicates are inserted in any case.
.